# Is it possible to create an icon in the toolbar for firebreath plugin

Tags: javascript, firebreath

I have created a firebreath plugin and I have a method like MyJsFunction() , this method can be called in javascript.

I want an icon in my browser toolbar like an add-on for my plugin, so that by clicking on that icon I can call my method, is this possible in plugin.

because my plugin has to work for all webpages, not only for single page.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The functionality you are looking for is not something that plugins are capable of doing -- you need an extension for that.  See http://npapi.com/extensions for more information on the difference.

You could use an extension *with* a plugin to potentially do this.